# Dynamic rewrite rule - based on a hitcounter OR timestamp

Tags: mod-rewrite, dynamic

Sorry for the lack of coherence with sys-admin stuff... I'm a programmer ;)

I have the need to switch front-end's of a website based on either a hit-counter or some kind of timer ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701831/switch-front-ends-of-a-website-after-x-amount-of-hits)).  Is this possible with `mod_rewrite`? any other interesting techniques?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? some kind of load balancing? could you please explain a bit more, then we might be able to really help you? thanks

Answer (score 0):

This post talks about how to serve alternate content based on time using apache's mod_rewrite:

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/time_hour-rewritecond-time.html

Hopefully it helps lead you in the right direction